# Any other methods to show 3 dots or truncate in TextView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview, android-design-library

- My TextView Tag looks like this

  ```
          <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:drawableEnd="@drawable/search_pickup_address"
          android:drawablePadding="@dimen/space"
          android:scrollHorizontally="false"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:inputType="text"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:minLines="1" />
  ```

  [image]
- I have set all this attributes

  ```
          android:scrollHorizontally="false"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:maxLines="1"
          android:minLines="1"
  ```
- As Single line true method is deprecated

  ```
          android:singleLine="true"
  ```
- When i have used this method dots are showing fine.

  ```
   String label;
   if (string.length() >= 35) {
      label= data.substring(0, 35)+ "...";
   } else {
      label= data;

   }
     textView.setText(label);
  ```
- But is there any direct method like

  ```
   android:singleLine="true"
  ```

Comment: Have you thought about the possibility of fading the end of a TextView instead of an ellipsize?

Comment: Are you just asking how to fix the ellipsize? Or do you really want another method to do it?

Comment: i am just asking for other method.. like can this only be achieve in XML.

Comment: If you mean, can it be done strictly in the layout XML, then yes. Remove the `inputType` attribute from your `<TextView>` element.

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
 android:ellipsize="end"
 android:maxLines="1"
 android:minLines="1"
 android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but i am looking for other method which are not mentioned by me.

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You can user attribute:

> android:ellipsize="end"

---

> android:singleLine="true"

I hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for the response but i am looking for other method which are not mentioned by me

Comment: Can you share it? :)